# Grid Columns with different resize "priorities"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a layout with 5 columns (1 and 5 same size, 2 and 4 same size):

|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |

We allow the user to resize the app horizontally (shrink it) and the behavior I'm trying to achieve is the following: shrink columns 1 and 5 until they disappear

|1|  2  |  3  |  4  |5|

||  2  |  3  |  4  ||

|  2  |  3  |  4  |

Then and only then, start shrinking 2 and 4 until a minimum width (3 always stays the same size)

I've tried this with a single Grid and nested Grids also but I can't reproduce the expected behavior. Like the tittle says, I'd like to prioritize which columns shrink first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce that using three Grids

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid  x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Grid.Column="0" Width="200"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Grid.Column="1" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>

        <Grid  x:Name="Grid3" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="Grid5" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Grid.Column="0" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Grid.Column="1" Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**[The Result](https://i.gyazo.com/d9e577c2f652dd2f0f78878fc311dc29.mp4)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is example.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*" MaxWidth="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="White" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="White" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1000*" MaxWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="PaleGreen" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="PaleGreen" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```